# Compound operators in Dash DataTable front-end filter

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Is it possible to filter Dash DataTable (dt) columns by compound operators in the front-end? For e.g. I have a column 'NumDays' and  filter by `> 6` finds records where 'NumDays' is greater than 6.

But how to filter for `((NumDays > 6) & (NumDays <= 15?))` in front-end? And is there a help-page for query syntax? The official filtering [page](https://dash.plot.ly/datatable/filtering) also seems to have simple operators as filters. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&&` seems to work for me. I'm using Python 3.6.1. See example code:

```py
style_data_conditional=[
        {
            'if': {
                'column_id': 'avf',
                'filter_query': '{avf} < 10000'
            },
            'backgroundColor': '#ff6961', # red
        },
        {
            'if': {
                'column_id': 'avf',
                'filter_query': '({avf} < 12000) && ({avf} >= 10000)'
            },
            'backgroundColor': 'yellow', # yellow
        },
        {
            'if': {
                'column_id': 'avf',
                'filter_query': '{avf} >= 12000'
            },
            'backgroundColor': '#7CFC00', # green
        },
    ]
```