# Plotly Dash datatable - use multiple filtering conditions in the same column

Tags: plotly-dash, plotly-python

Currently in Plotly Dash, you can filter on data tables by typing in expressions such as '< 90 ' or 'eq 50'. Here is some sample code along with the documentation for filtering:

https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/filtering

```
from dash import Dash, dash_table, Input, Output, callback
import pandas as pd


app = Dash(__name__)

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminder2007.csv')

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    id='table-filtering-be',
    columns=[
        {"name": i, "id": i} for i in sorted(df.columns)
    ],

    filter_action='custom',
    filter_query=''
)

operators = [['ge ', '>='],
             ['le ', '<='],
             ['lt ', '<'],
             ['gt ', '>'],
             ['ne ', '!='],
             ['eq ', '='],
             ['contains '],
             ['datestartswith ']]


def split_filter_part(filter_part):
    for operator_type in operators:
        for operator in operator_type:
            if operator in filter_part:
                name_part, value_part = filter_part.split(operator, 1)
                name = name_part[name_part.find('{') + 1: name_part.rfind('}')]

                value_part = value_part.strip()
                v0 = value_part[0]
                if (v0 == value_part[-1] and v0 in ("'", '"', '`')):
                    value = value_part[1: -1].replace('\\' + v0, v0)
                else:
                    try:
                        value = float(value_part)
                    except ValueError:
                        value = value_part

                # word operators need spaces after them in the filter string,
                # but we don't want these later
                return name, operator_type[0].strip(), value

    return [None] * 3


@callback(
    Output('table-filtering-be', "data"),
    Input('table-filtering-be', "filter_query"))
def update_table(filter):
    filtering_expressions = filter.split(' && ')
    dff = df
    for filter_part in filtering_expressions:
        col_name, operator, filter_value = split_filter_part(filter_part)

        if operator in ('eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge'):
            # these operators match pandas series operator method names
            dff = dff.loc[getattr(dff[col_name], operator)(filter_value)]
        elif operator == 'contains':
            dff = dff.loc[dff[col_name].str.contains(filter_value)]
        elif operator == 'datestartswith':
            # this is a simplification of the front-end filtering logic,
            # only works with complete fields in standard format
            dff = dff.loc[dff[col_name].str.startswith(filter_value)]

    return dff.to_dict('records')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My question - Is it possible to enter multiple different filters in the same application? For example, if I wanted to search for values in a column that are in between 50 and 60  (50 < values < 60)? In all of the documentation I have gone through, I have been able to enter one filtering condition per column. This means that I would only be able to search for values that are greater than 50 or less than 60.

I have tried running the code provided and typing in filter expressions such as '< 50 && > 60', but have not been able to return what I want.

I have also viewed this question, but the answer provided is not working for me: [Compound operators in Dash DataTable front-end filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56448460/compound-operators-in-dash-datatable-front-end-filter)